# Steam plotting of vector field showing empty output

Tags: plotting, vector

I am trying to plot the stream lines for a vector field function, whose definition is exported to the wdx file uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zn3f3jtqkeve68y/ReadyFieldXY.wdx?dl=0). The following simple code returns an empty plot:

```
ReadyFieldXY = 
Import["C:\\ReadyFieldXY.wdx"];
a0 = 0.00055;
StreamPlot[Abs[ReadyFieldXY], {x, -a0/2, a0/2}, {y, -a0/2, a0/2}]
```

[image]

I am not sure what is wrong here. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What does Abs[ReadyFieldXY] /. {x -> 0.0, y -> 0.0} give?

Comment: Just as `StreamPlot[{x^10000, y^10000}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]`

Comment: @cvgmt But what can one do if their function is indeed like $x^{10000}$ and wanted to see the StreamPlot? Is there a way around this?

Comment: @BrettChamion It gives 1/0. But what if that specific point was not met in the gird being plotted. And if it were, then why didn't Mathematica complain about it?  In fact, I think the plot gives very teeny tiny points that are not visible. When I try plot it over the range {x, a0/200, a0/2}, {y, a0/200, a0/2} (to avoid 0,0 point), I get a plot with very faint dots. How do I go around this to show stream arrows clearly? This field is found from a physical system and I need to find a way visualize its stream. I can avoid certain problematic points (like 0,0) but I need to plot it everywhere else

Comment: I don't think `1/0` should be an issue at `(x,y)->(0,0)`. `StreamPlot[Abs[{1/x, 1/y}], {x, -0.1, 0.1}, {y, -0.1, 0.1}]` works fine. Have you tried changing `StreamPoints` and `StreamScale`? Can you edit your question to include the vector field functions so people don't have to download anything?

Comment: @DerekH Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, the fields are generated through a very complex process that is quite long code and not possible to share, so the option for me was to charge funnction file itself. Your comment makes me wonder whether it might be just a matter of multiplying the function by some scalar to make it visible...